# Array with integers and string in iphone app

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, arrays

Im creating a rugby app where I need to make a record of every time a match event occurs. So every time there is a pass they click pass, every time theres a tackle they press tackle etc.
This information then is going to be put in an external database so it can be also viewed on a website.

So the events in the app will be recorded and look similar to this.

1, pass
2, pass
3, try
4, pass
etc

When the user clicks up upload itll be uploaded to the database so will be using sql.

Because the pass is a string and ID is a number will I have problems?

Is this the best way to go about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store Strings and Numbers in the same array use `NSNumber` instead of `int`

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNUmber numberWithInt:3]
```

or

```
NSNumber *myNumber = @3;
```

Later , when uploading data, if you want you can retrieve the human-readable string value from the integer like this,

```
   [myNumber stringValue];
```

Comment: thanks so much could you please elaborate as im fairly new to this. If possible could i have some code of making the actual array with the fields ID and event... and the upload part. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to create an mixed object Array with Strings and Numbers in it? Or, You just need to store strings like, "Pass 1", "Try 4"  in an array?

Comment: in the database it will have these fields .... id , event, ...id is an integer as its the primary key and event is a string